# Testing sql connection with tedious using jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, tedious

I have tested this class manually with a real sql database and it works, but I wonder if there is a way to automate the tests (ideally, without accessing a real database). For that I would like to mock tedious, so I won't need to run a database query in the tests. How should I test the method getRequest using jest?

```
const { Connection, Request } = require('tedious')

class SQLConnector {
  /**
   * Keeps the configuration of a sql connection.
   * @param {object} sqlServerConfig Configuration object used by the tedious library.
   */
  constructor (sqlServerConfig) {
    if (typeof (sqlServerConfig) !== 'object') {
      throw new Error('sqlServerConfig should be an object')
    }
    this.sqlServerConfig = sqlServerConfig
  }
  /**
   * Runs a sql query
   * @param {string} query sql query to be run
   * @returns {Array.<object>} Array with entries from the sql query
   */
  getRequest (query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const connection = new Connection(this.sqlServerConfig)

      connection.connect((err) => {
        if (err) { reject(err) }

        const dataArray = []

        const req = new Request(query, (err) => {
          if (err) { reject(err) }
          connection.close()
          resolve(dataArray)
        })

        req.on('row', (columns) => {
          const data = {}
          columns.forEach(function (column) {
            data[column.metadata.colName.toLowerCase()] = column.value
          })
          dataArray.push(data)
        })

        connection.execSql(req)
      })
    })
  }
}

module.exports = {
  SQLConnector
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't. Use a test double of that connector from the perspective of testing the business logic, but if you try to unit test it you'll end up writing complex test doubles of an interface (tedious's) that you don't own. This would then be tested at an _integration_ level, against a real DB (maybe in a container/in-memory).

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. In the places where I use SQLConnector, I test the business logic by assuming that getRequest(query) returns an Array of object (i.e. I mock SQLConnector to return what i expect). But I still would like to check that SQLConnector calls tedious correctly. I have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089021/how-to-mock-tedious-module-sql-connection-functions-in-jest but I don't know how use the mock. I also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71041981/testing-a-nodejs-function-that-connects-to-sql-server-through-tedious-with-jest but Iam confused about its use.